# Tableview не заполняется полностью

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

У меня есть несколько `tableview` и я хочу чтобы выбранные значение отображались 3-ем `tableview`.
Для этого есть массив, который собирает ответы. Но когда я делаю пуш на контроллер с результатами отображается только последнее значение.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

firstarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //array with questions
[self.firstarr addObject:[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //collects the data properly

BodyDetailViewController* vc =[[BodyDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BodyDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
vc.someArray = firstarr; //some array - ViewController with Results.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry99, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Comment: ok, переписал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в методе каждый раз инициализируется массив.

```
firstarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //array with questions
[self.firstarr addObject:[self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //collects the data properly
```

Вынесите инициализацию в другое место, например в метод `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Comment: Еще при инициализации надо использовать self если у вас retain-свойство.
self.firstarr = [NSMutableArray array];
А вот при добавлении в массив self писать не обязательно.